# Arduino Uno + SIM808 EVB 3.2.4 not working properly?

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, gps

So recently I found this tutorial online about the SIM808. It looked super cool so I ordered the sim808 evb 3.2.4 off amazon. Hooked up the module and connected the RX (11) and (10) TX pins.

Here is the code I'm working with tried to follow along as best I could with the tutorial but now I am completely confused, purchased a SIM card activated the SIM card and it seems to be connecting just fine

In the serial monitor sometimes I receive this: 14:05:06.243 -> Init Success, please send SMS message to me!

But most of the time I'm receiving this: 14:04:37.586 -> Sim808 init error

#include <DFRobot_sim808.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define MESSAGE_LENGTH 160
char message[MESSAGE_LENGTH];
int messageIndex = 0;
char MESSAGE[300];
char lat[12];
char lon[12];
char wspeed[12];

char phone[16];
char datetime[24];

#define PIN_TX 10
#define PIN_RX 11
SoftwareSerial mySerial(PIN_TX,PIN_RX);
DFRobot_SIM808 sim808(&mySerial);//Connect RX,TX,PWR,

void sendSMS();
void getGPS();
void readSMS();

void setup()
{
mySerial.begin(9600);
Serial.begin(9600);

//******** Initialize sim808 module *************
while(!sim808.init())
{
Serial.print("Sim808 init error\r\n");
delay(1000);
}
delay(3000);

Serial.println("SIM Init success");

Serial.println("Init Success, please send SMS message to me!");
}

void loop()
{
//*********** Detecting unread SMS ************************
messageIndex = sim808.isSMSunread();

//*********** At least, there is one UNREAD SMS ***********
if (messageIndex > 0)
{

```
  readSMS();
  getGPS();
  sendSMS();

  //************* Turn off the GPS power ************
  sim808.detachGPS();

  Serial.println("Please send SMS message to me!");
```

}
}

void readSMS()
{
Serial.print("messageIndex: ");
Serial.println(messageIndex);

sim808.readSMS(messageIndex, message, MESSAGE_LENGTH, phone, datetime);

//***********In order not to full SIM Memory, is better to delete it**********
sim808.deleteSMS(messageIndex);
Serial.print("From number: ");
Serial.println(phone);
Serial.print("Datetime: ");
Serial.println(datetime);
Serial.print("Recieved Message: ");
Serial.println(message);
}

void getGPS()
{
while(!sim808.attachGPS())
{
Serial.println("Open the GPS power failure");
delay(1000);
}
delay(3000);

Serial.println("Open the GPS power success");

while(!sim808.getGPS())
{

}

Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.year);
Serial.print("/");
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.month);
Serial.print("/");
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.day);
Serial.print(" ");
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.hour);
Serial.print(":");
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.minute);
Serial.print(":");
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.second);
Serial.print(":");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.centisecond);
Serial.print("latitude :");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.lat);
Serial.print("longitude :");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.lon);
Serial.print("speed_kph :");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.speed_kph);
Serial.print("heading :");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.heading);
Serial.println();

float la = sim808.GPSdata.lat;
float lo = sim808.GPSdata.lon;
float ws = sim808.GPSdata.speed_kph;

dtostrf(la, 4, 6, lat); //put float value of la into char array of lat. 4 = number of digits before decimal sign. 6 = number of digits after the decimal sign.
dtostrf(lo, 4, 6, lon); //put float value of lo into char array of lon
dtostrf(ws, 6, 2, wspeed);  //put float value of ws into char array of wspeed

sprintf(MESSAGE, "Latitude : %s\nLongitude : %s\nWind Speed : %s kph\nMy Module Is Working. Mewan Indula Pathirage. Try With This Link.\nhttp://www.latlong.net/Show-Latitude-Longitude.html\nhttp://maps.google.com/maps?q=%s,%s\n", lat, lon, wspeed, lat, lon);
}

void sendSMS()
{
Serial.println("Start to send message ...");

Serial.println(MESSAGE);
Serial.println(phone);

sim808.sendSMS(phone,MESSAGE);
}`

Comment: the code is a mess. please format it properly so that it is legible

Comment: why are you asking if it is working properly? ... do you not know what you want it to do and what it is doing?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use AT command ..then using some kind of library. You need to dig into library for better information.

https://randomnerdtutorials.com/sim900-gsm-gprs-shield-arduino/
Go through this link....this will give you a rough idea.